# How to print a div section with the document style sheet css intact?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How do I print a div section with the style sheet/CSS of the parent.

Is there a way to create a new DOM and hide all elements except the CSS and the div section to be printed.

I am using AngularJS/Bootstrap

I have seen some example in https://github.com/gilf/ngPrint, but it seems the CSS is not getting carried over to the printable window.

Thanks

Comment: why not use a directive?

Comment: yes, I should I have clarified, I am using a directive. ngPrint above is a directive, but it doesn't copy over the CSS? Or maybe I am missing something

Comment: can you include a plunker of what its doing now and you expected?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure of your situation but would a print stylesheet take care of this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: Here is the plunker of my code. It uses ngprint (http://plnkr.co/edit/gchbJn?p=preview)